# How can I create a hash from json response in perl

Tags: perl

I have a json response such as

```
{  
  "extId" : "abc:3",
  "intId" : "val:0500019141EBE54B",
  "type" : "Map"
}{
  "extId" : "abc:4",
  "intId" : "val:0500012BEA8FEC15",
  "type" : "Map"
}{  
  "extId" : "abc:3",
  "intId" : "val:0500019141EBE54B",
  "type" : "Map"
}
```

I want to create a hash such as `$hash{abc:3} = val:0500019141EBE54B`, so that I can verify that the same `intId` is being created for the same `extId`. Thanks for help.

Comment: [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) perhaps?

Comment: more specifically, [from_json](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#from_json) does what you need.

Comment: That's not JSON. Missing commas between `}{`, and missing `[]` around the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @data = <DATA>;

s/[\r\n\s{}",]//g, s/(ext|int)Id:|type:Map// for @data;

my %hash = grep length, @data;

print Dumper \%hash;

__DATA__

{  
  "extId" : "abc:3",
  "intId" : "val:0500019141EBE54B",
  "type" : "Map"
}{
  "extId" : "abc:4",
  "intId" : "val:0500012BEA8FEC15",
  "type" : "Map"
}{  
  "extId" : "abc:3",
  "intId" : "val:0500019141EBE54B",
  "type" : "Map"
}
```

Note that fields (extId, intId) are obligatory.

Answer (score 0):

What you haven't posted isn't JSON. Given you said it's from a JSON response, I'm going to make a guess it's a transposition error. If that's *not* the case, this won't work - but you should probably poke the people giving you the JSON and tell them they're doing it wrong.

You should also note - the hash you request - you have duplicate keys in `intId`. You will therefore lose one of them if you convert that to a hash.

However with the above assumptions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $JSON_text = '[
   {
      "extId" : "abc:3",
      "type" : "Map",
      "intId" : "val:0500019141EBE54B"
   },
   {
      "intId" : "val:0500012BEA8FEC15",
      "type" : "Map",
      "extId" : "abc:4"
   },
   {
      "intId" : "val:0500019141EBE54B",
      "type" : "Map",
      "extId" : "abc:3"
   }
]';

#turn JSON into a perl data structure. 
#In this case, an array of anon hashes. 
my $json_obj =  decode_json ( $JSON_text );
print Dumper \$json_obj;

#process that perl data structure, and extract the keys
# use the fact that a list of paired values can be 
#assigned to a hash as if they were key-value pairs:
my %int_ext = map { $_ -> {extId}, 
                    $_ -> {intId} }
                            @{$json_obj};
print Dumper \%int_ext;
```

This makes our `%int_ext` hash:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'abc:3' => 'val:0500019141EBE54B',
          'abc:4' => 'val:0500012BEA8FEC15'
        };
```

Note - as you have two `abc:3` keys, you "lose" one of them. (The first one is overwritten, not that that matters in this case).